# Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint (Error msg:2627)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I use sql server an i try to run the query below:

```
declare @ProductID int
set @ProductID=322

INSERT INTO table_Customer (ProductID,Type,CompanyID) 
SELECT @ProductID,' ',CompanyID 
FROM table_Companies 
WHERE CompanyActive=1
```

And i get the error below:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 19
>
> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_table_Customer'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.table_Customer'. The duplicate key value
>   is (322, , , , , , ).

Find below table's definition.

```
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].table_Customer(

> [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
> 
> [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,

> [Type] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
> 
> [CompanyID] [int] NULL,
> 
> [RoleID] [int] NULL,
> 
> 

>  CONSTRAINT [PK_table_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  (
> 
> [CustomerID] ASC
> 
> )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =
> OFF,
> 
> ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON
> [PRIMARY],
> 
>  CONSTRAINT [IX_table_Customer] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED  (

>   [ProductID] ASC,
> 
>   [CompID] ASC,
> 
>   [CompManager] ASC
> 
> )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =
> OFF,
> 
> ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON
> [PRIMARY]
> 
> ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is the index unique? The most obvious explanation is that you *are* trying to insert a duplicate entry

Comment: The unique key constraint is placed on which column.? That column value is violating the constarint

Comment: Post the index's definition

Comment: check for the duplicate value

Comment: I find it very odd you have a `productID` in a `customer` table.

Comment: The error message didn't help you enough?   What part of it did you not understand?

Comment: I have add table's definition. I know that i add the same value many times. That's made by porpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you used will *repeat* the same `@ProductID` value for every active company in the `table_Companies` table.

```
SELECT @ProductID,' ',CompanyID 
FROM table_Companies 
WHERE CompanyActive=1
```

If the index contains the ProductID column only, or at least it *doesn't* contain the CompanyID field as well, this will result in duplicate ProductID entries.

Answer (score 2):

You are possibly inserting *multiple* rows as they are being returned from the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO table_Customer (ProductID,Type,CompanyID)
SELECT @ProductID, ' ', CompanyID
FROM   table_Companies
WHERE  CompanyActive = 1  -- How many rows does this produce...?
```

Note that `@ProductID` is a FIXED value in this query, so it will be the same (322) for all selected-and-then-inserted rows.

Your index is complaining that you can't insert rows having the same set of index values. So either there is already a record with those values, or the `SELECT` produces duplicates, or both of these combined.

Comment: currently is 43 rows but this can change.

Comment: For further analysis, please include the definition of index `IX_table_Customer` into the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that you already have a a unique key of **322** in the customer table

```
Select * from table_Customer where productID = 322;
```

Answer (score 0):

ProductID is probably identity. if it is really a must. Remove it and add it back when finished. But clearly you already have data for id 322

Comment: and it is violation of primary key. you can not have two or more data with same ID. specially because your ID is identity (When column a is identity it means it is auto-increment field). All columns that make a PRIMARY KEY must be unique. e.g. you have columns a b c (where a and b are keys) with data 1 2 3 you can not have another set of data 1 2 4 but can have 2 3 3. Hope this helps you.

Comment: > [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
> 
> [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,      I add ProductID multiple times, not CustomerID

Comment: check your constraint